# Query not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, activity

I want to see all emails sent to a specific subscriber

I have created a DE with the field `subscriberKey` is only and primary key
I then want to set up an Query Activity based on the Query

```
SELECT j.EmailName, s.EmailAddress from  _Job j 
INNER JOIN _Sent se on j.JobID = se.JobID
INNER JOIN _Subscribers s ON se.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE se.EventDate < GetDate()
```

However as the `subscriberKey` is required within my Target DE I get this error message when I want to save the Query

> A problem occurred creating your query definition. Please contact Customer Service for additional information.
>   Name: Email sent to spec individual 
>   External Key: a7fc18e8-051d-4f53-8d98-5bf73b0dc6f8
>   Error saving the Query field.Field 'SubscriberKey' is a required for the Target Data Extension. Ensure this field is specified in your query text.

Where do I enter the `subscriberKey` for the specific individual in the query text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also select the susbcriberkey in your query or make it not required.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
s.SubscriberKey
,s.EmailAddress as Email
,j.EmailName
,s.EmailAddress from  _Job j 
INNER JOIN _Sent se on j.JobID = se.JobID
INNER JOIN _Subscribers s ON se.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE se.EventDate < GetDate()
```

Comment: I added you query text in my query and it errored saying I needed at least on non-required field in my DE so I added Email adress as second field

Comment: When I save the query now it gives me the error message

Comment: An error occurred saving the definition:
A problem occurred creating your query definition. Please contact Customer Service for additional information.
Name: Email sent to spec individual 
External Key: a7fc18e8-051d-4f53-8d98-5bf73b0dc6f8
Error saving the Query field.Field 'Email' is a required for the Target Data Extension. Ensure this field is specified in your query text.

Comment: Can you please take a screen shot of your target data extension? So we can add all required fields?? adding email now

Comment: Have you tried it? Added an alias tag to the email line

Comment: If this question is answered you should accept it. If you have a new one it's the norm to ask a new question and I (or someone) can answer it

Comment: Its working now. Yay. Thank you very much for your kind help. I am new in this environment. Didnt mean to step on your toes.

Comment: Lol! You weren't . Doing this at work so comments are short! Welcome to the community between